# Can you please review my work?

Tags: sound-design, demo-reel

Hi 
I chanced upon this awesome forum while looking for answers whether to burden myself with a debt and attend VFS or not....i got some pretty good answers to it and many other topics.. so thanks to you all...

Here in india, sound designers and film audio people are mostly from the prestigious FTII film school and a monopoly of them. Game audio is just catching up.

I wanna improve my work and build a new demo reel. This one below is right out of SAE and been 1.5yrs since. Now im working in the industry in Mumbai, India, but as a dubbing and mixing engg and not as a sound designer. So im putting up my old work for review and also starting new work at home to sharpen my skills. Im fluent with Protools 8 HD and Nuendo4 (though using only protools at work)

Please listen to my work and comment. Also where can i find free videos to sound design for? Im starting to learn Fmod & Ableton live on my own and expeerimenting with Reason.

[EDIT] Changed link

1. Demo reel from college

http://www.4shared.com/video/ghBpP9Au/Audio_Post_Production-Sound_De.html

1. 1st Attempt at sound sythesis. Done last month.

[soundcloud]auralchef/sets/1st-sound-synthesis-attempt/[/soundcloud]

thanks

Comment: Rigga rigga rigga..rigga rigga rigga..rigga rigga rigga rigga rigga lol sorry it just popped up in my head after looking at your user name, I don't even listen to hindi music..

Comment: Your video has been blocked by Fox. This is what happens when you use copyrighted material without asking first. Always go to the source first, whether it be public relations or otherwise, you get permission first!

Comment: How do i get permission from the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By not having a professional do the voiceover for your work you're downgrading the quality. I realise it was a school project and you've lost the files, maybe re-do it without voiceover? Or do some extra scenes.

You can also tell you've re-used the same section of a tank sample over and over and its rather tiresome. Need more variation.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a more detailed review, later, but my first recommendation is to remove all the music from your reel, and all the narrator stuff -- they're both getting in the way of the sound design.

Comment: Hi thanks. It was a college project and no longer have the sessions, so cant remove anything...please try to view it as a complete package... there are other videos in it too with hardly any voice.

Answer (score 0):

@edmatthews82, & @Dave Matney

thanks guys for the replies. Since im a dubbing engineer now, i have made contacts with voice over and dubbing artists. I can get someone to redo the VO.

About the tank sound, its an old russian T-55 tank, for which i wasnt finding any sounds. so looking at some youtube videos of it, i created the sound by layering a bulldozer, generator, and some more sounds. So through out the movie its gonna be the same. There cant be a variation in it.

Yeah the sounds i have repeated are that of demolition and wall falling.

What about the airplane engine sounds that i created? Any comments on it?

Comment: I meant add variation, like engine revs here and there, it sounds like the same 20 second clip used everytime at the same spot. If he turns the tank have it change, slows down, gear shifting etc